# Can I use `omp_get_thread_num()` on the GPU?

Tags: g++, gpu, openmp, pgi, offloading

I have OpenMP code which works on the CPU by having each thread manage memory addressed by the thread's id number, accessible via `omp_get_thread_num()`. This works well on the CPU, but can it work on the GPU?

A MWE is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){
  const int SIZE = 400000;

  int *m;
  m = new int[SIZE];

  #pragma omp target
  {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
      m[i] = omp_get_thread_num();
  }

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    std::cout<<m[i]<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

---

It works fine on the GPU for me with GCC. You need to map `m` thoough e.g. like this

```
#pragma omp target map(tofrom:m[0:SIZE])
```

I compiled like this

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector so.cpp
```

You can see an example for system without offloading here

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e756410d6e2db61

A method I use to find out the number of teams and threads before doing work is this:

```
#pragma omp target teams defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)
{
    nteams = omp_get_num_teams();
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
}
```

On my system with GCC 7.2, Ubuntu 17.10, and `gcc-offload-nvptx` with a GTX 1060 I get  `nteams = 30` and `nthreads = 8`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148721/2542702) where I do a custom reduction for a target region using threads and teams.  With `-offload=disable` `nteams = 1` and `nthreads = 8` (4 core/8 hardware thread CPU).

---

I added `-fopt-info` to the compile options and I get only the message

```
note: basic block vectorized
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be **no**.

Compiling with PGI using:

```
pgc++ -fast -mp -ta=tesla,pinned,cc60 -Minfo=all test2.cpp
```

gives:

```
13, Parallel region activated
    Parallel loop activated with static block schedule
    Loop not vectorized/parallelized: contains call
14, Parallel region terminated
```

whereas compiling with GCC using

```
g++ -O3 test2.cpp -fopenmp -fopt-info
```

gives

```
test2.cpp:17: note: not vectorized: loop contains function calls or data references that cannot be analyzed
test2.cpp:17: note: bad data references.
```